# C++ struct object calling a function

Tags: c++, function, object, struct

This is simply just frustrating me to the brink of implosion. I do not know why I cannot figure this out, however, I need some assistance. Or at least some rhetorical questions to lead me in the right direction.

I have an object called expression. This object is a struct of tokenType tokens.

```
//expression.h file
struct expression
{

    int numTokens ;
    tokenType tokens[MAX_TOKENS_IN_EXPRESSION] ;

    void print() const ;
    ...
}
```

tokenType is simply either a number (operand) or a symbol (operator)

Given that, I have these lines of code in my test.cpp file:

```
expression expr1 , expr2 ;
...
errorCode = expr1.toPostfix( expr2 ) ;
```

I have to implement toPostFix( [parameter] );
Its function declaration is as follows:

```
//in expression.cpp
int expression::toPostfix( expression & pfx ) const
{
    int result = 1; 

    //how do I read in the 'expression' that is calling this method???

    return result;
}
```

Where if result = 0 the expression was successfully converted to PostFix notation, unsuccessful otherwise.

The issue I am having is the comment in the middle of the provided code...how do I retrieve the data being passed into the function???

I'm not asking for code, because I feel like this is a very simple question, and just a brain fart on my part. So if anyone could please just kick me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Just curious if you searched at all, because there are quite a few questions like this on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried, searching SO and google, but I guess I was asking the wrong question, I apologize for being redundant

Comment: No apologies necessary, it's just that this is pretty baseline C++, and any tutorial/etc. covers this--being able to find stuff is a really important skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
expr1.toPostfix(expr2);
```

then the pointer to `expr1` is passed as the (hidden) `this` pointer inside the method.

The result of this (no pun intended) is that you can access member functions and variables on the called object inside `expression::toPostfix()` with or without using `this->`. Usually, C++ programmers omit `this->` when accessing members.

Of course you can access the methods of `expr2` by using `pfx` inside your method.

I must say, this is pretty fundamental C++ stuff. You might consider following through a C++ tutorial to solidify your grasp on things.

Comment: Yea I know it's fundamental stuff, I obviously need to continue practicing, but this was really just frustrating me. Thank you for the explanation though